# How to cast SAAJ object during handling SOAP message?

Tags: java, soap, casting, saaj

Colleagues, i have xml which need to be handle and configure before sending to client:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns2:request xmlns:ns2="http://mayacomp/Generic/Ws">
            <in xmlns="http://mayacomp/Generic/Ws">
                <requestHeader>
                    <requestUid>1234567890</requestUid>
                    <ns2:requestTimestamp>2015-02-11T07:46:00.000</ns2:requestTimestamp>
                </requestHeader>
                <ns2:FullDataView>
                    <ns2:ApplicationData>
                        <ns2:ProductType>0</ns2:ProductType>
                    </ns2:ApplicationData>
                    <ns2:ProductDetails>
                        <ns2:ProductCode>605</ns2:ProductCode>
                    </ns2:ProductDetails>
                    <ns2:Applicant>
                        <ns2:Surname>Клавиатурова</ns2:Surname>
                        <ns2:Address>
                            <ns2:Type>1</ns2:Type>
                        </ns2:Address>
                        <ns2:Address>
                            <ns2:Type>2</ns2:Type>
                        </ns2:Address>
                        <ns2:Email>test@test.ru</ns2:Email>
                    </ns2:Applicant>
                </ns2:FullDataView>
            </in>
        </ns2:request>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I use the next method to configure soap message:

```
public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) {

                        SaajSoapMessage saajSoapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage)message;

                    try {

                        SOAPMessage soapMessage = saajSoapMessage.getSaajMessage();
                        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
                        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
                        log.info("SOAPEnvelope prefix " +  envelope.getPrefix());
                        envelope.removeNamespaceDeclaration(envelope.getPrefix());
                        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
                        envelope.setPrefix("soapenv");

                        /*Remove header*/
                        SOAPHeader header = soapMessage.getSOAPHeader();
                        header.detachNode();


                        SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();
                        log.info("SOAPBody prefix " +  body.getPrefix());
                        body.removeNamespaceDeclaration(body.getPrefix()) ;
                        body.addNamespaceDeclaration("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
                        body.setPrefix("soapenv");


                        /*Prepare body elements*/
                        Iterator itBodyElements = body.getChildElements();

                        String elementName = null;
                        /*Log all elements from body*/
                        log.info("Body elements: ");
                        NodeList nodeList = body.getElementsByTagName("*") ;
                        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                                log.info(node.getNodeName());
                            }
                        }

                        /*Config body elements*/
                        while (itBodyElements.hasNext()) 
                        { 
                          Object o = itBodyElements.next();
                          SOAPBodyElement bodyElement = (SOAPBodyElement) o;
                          log.info("Elements from 'Body' element = " + bodyElement.getLocalName() );

                          Iterator it2 = bodyElement.getChildElements();
                                 while (it2.hasNext()) 
                                 { 
                                      Object requestElement = it2.next();
                                      SOAPBodyElement bodyRequest = (SOAPBodyElement) requestElement;
                                      log.info("  Elements from '"+ bodyElement.getLocalName() + "' element = " + bodyRequest.getLocalName()); 
                                      bodyRequest.removeNamespaceDeclaration(bodyRequest.getPrefix());
                                      bodyRequest.setPrefix("");

                                       Iterator it3 = bodyRequest.getChildElements();
                                            while (it3.hasNext())
                                            {
                                              Object bodyRequestElement = it3.next();
                                              SOAPBodyElement requestElementName = (SOAPBodyElement) bodyRequestElement;
                                              log.info("   Elements from 'In' name = " + requestElementName.getLocalName());
                                              requestElementName.setPrefix("");
                                              elementName =  requestElementName.getLocalName();

                                              Iterator it4  = requestElementName.getChildElements();                                              

                                                while (it4.hasNext()) 
                                                          {
                                                              Object o4 = it4.next();
                                                              SOAPBodyElement bodyElement4 = (SOAPBodyElement) o4;
                                                              log.info("    Element from '" + elementName + "' name = " + bodyElement4.getLocalName());
                                                              bodyElement4.setPrefix("");

                                                            Iterator it5 =  bodyElement4.getChildElements(); 

                                                            while (it5.hasNext())
                                                            {
                                                                Object o5 = it5.next(); 
                                                                //What it tried?
                                                            // TextImpl child5 = (TextImpl) o5; //java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.ElementImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.TextImpl
                                                            // ElementImpl child5 = (ElementImpl) o5; //Result:java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.ElementImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.TextImpl
                                                            // SOAPElement child5 = (SOAPElement)o5; //java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.TextImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement
                                                            // SOAPBodyElement child5 = (SOAPBodyElement) o5;  //java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.TextImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.soap.SOAPBodyElement
                                                                log.info(o5.getClass().toString());
                                                            }
                                                           }
                                            }
                                 }

                       } 
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                }
```

The problem is that i can not cast the Object o5 (`class com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.ElementImpl`) to any types described in code.
How correctly cast the object o5?

Thank you.

Comment: Add conditionals with `instance of`?

Comment: Didn't understand.... Explain, please. I need to add 'if' like `if (o5 instanceof 'class com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.ElementImpl')`? also `log.info(o5.getClass().toString())` returns  class `com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.ElementImpl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPElement.html#getChildElements()), the `getChildElements` method has the following behavior:

> Returns an `Iterator` over all the immediate child `Node`s of this element. This includes `javax.xml.soap.Text` objects as well as `SOAPElement` objects.

Therefore, before attempting to cast, you need to check whether the node is a `Text` or a `SOAPElement`.

Comment: Every element is SOAPElement.  Thank you.